# Excel VBA adding values of a column into a Combo box based on another Combo box

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add items in column A to combobox1 and then add item in column B to combobox2 based on combobox1 value.

```
   A   B
1  a  ddd
2  a  fgh
3  a  jcv
4  b  ggh
5  b  ggg
6  b  fff
7  b  hhh
```

For example 
If I choose "b" in combobox1 then these strings should be added to combobox2: ggh, ggg, fff and hhh
My code doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
With Sheet3.ComboBox1

For Each Cell In Range("A1:A7")
.AddItem Cell.Value
Next

End With
Dim index As Integer
index = ComboBox1.value
Call combo2
End Sub


Private Sub combo2()

For Each Cell In Range("A1:A7")
Select Case index
    Case Is = a
        With ComboBox2

            .AddItem "offset(cell.address,1,1,1,0)"

        End With
    Case Is = b
        With ComboBox2
            .AddItem "offset(cell.address,1,1,1,0)"
        End With

End Select

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks really messed up much like your question. I can only try to point some mistakes.

Here's what you need to correct:

1. Declare `Index` as public so the other sub can access it. Outside of your first event sub, add the line `Public Index As String`.
2. You should use the case select like  `case "a"` and not `case Is = a`. The `Is` operator is used to compare object references, meanwhile, you're dealing with a simple datatype comparison.
3. In your `case "a"` and `case "b"` instructions, within yout `with` statement, use a `For Each` statement to loop through your range "B" for values. It would look like something like in the code sample below.
4. In your question, you say:

> *For example  If I choose "b" in combobox1 then these strings should be
>   added to combobox2: ggh, ggg, fff and hhh*

However, you're filling your first comobox with values from the column A and I can only assume you meant to say B, otherwise, your select case statement would not work.

Code sample:

```
For Each Cell in Range("B1:B7")
If Cell.Value = "a" Then
.AddItem Cell.Offset(0,1).Value
End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to fill the first combo box with column A and the second combo box with column B. Please have a look at the table in question.

Comment: That confirmed my suspension in answer. You incorporate my remarks to your code very easily then.